# get current time (timestamp) and save to db

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on tracking the time users spend in a session. What I'm doing is creating a token when they enter a session, and track when that was created_at.

That means I essentially have a starting point, now I want to be able to track the end point which is when they finish a session.

Luckily I already have an event tracker that tracks when they disconnect from a session, however what I'd like to accomplish now is when that tracker is activated then to store the end

```
session.on 'sessionDisconnected', (event) ->
  console.log 'You were disconnected from the session' + event.reason
  # track that session ended in database
  if event.reason == 'networkDisconnected'
    alert 'Your network connection terminated.'
  else if event.reason == 'clientDisconnected'
    console.log 'You closed the session'
  return
```

essentially where I have my comment is where I'd like to send a request to store the time in the database.

I'd like to save the timestamp in table "customers" and the column called "finished_at".

So how do I get the current time and save it as a timestamp into my customers.finished_at is my question.

Answer (score 0):

For current time in JavaScript use new Date() and to get timestamp from that use

var timeStamp = new Date().getTime();

Comment: How you communicate to your server? if you have restAPI/server call send this timeStamp as payload

Comment: Much more reliable to do that on the server, you can't be sure the client has their clock set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make a server entry point that updates the `finished_at` field. For instance:

`routes.rb`:

```
resources :customers do
  get :finish
end
```

`customers_controller.rb`:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def finish
    customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
    if customer.update(finished_at: Time.now)
      some_action
    else
      another_action
    end
  end
end
```

Then you have to make request to this entry point from your client:

```
GET /customers/:id/finish
```

(According to the REST it's not a good idea to use GET here. It is just to show the main idea)

Feel free to ask the details if needed.